# Reading a part of an XML file using C sharp

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

I have a list of paths of files on an XML file. I need to show these path files on a data grid view.  For now I have managed to show the exact number of rows as the same number of paths in the XML file but the paths do not show.  If someone could show me how to show file paths on data grid views I would be grateful

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "XML|*.xml";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(ofd.FileName);

            foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.SelectNodes("JobInfo/Folders/Folder"))
            {
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = node.InnerText;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: So what happens? Is the text not displayed, do you get an error, or ..?

Comment: I just tested it using a simple form with a button and a dataGridView and it worked fine, the xml file looked like this: <JobInfo>
<Folders>
<Folder>
Hey
</Folder>
</Folders>
</JobInfo>
Can you give more information about your setup?

Comment: @stuartd Number of rows are shown which are equal to the number of path files in the XML file but no text is shown.(text as in the path files)

Comment: @ sydan I have a form and in it i have a button which when pressed loads up a dialog file box to choose a file. Then the data in the XML  file chosen is shown in a datagrid view.  The problem is that it is not accepting File Paths example "C:\Thisisanexample\load" and that is not showing.

Comment: @Jack interesting, even when I change 'Hey' in my example to your example file path it still works for me. Can you put a screenshot up of your Form's layout and the configuration of the DataGridView as much info as possible? Also could you put your XML file in the post as well?

Comment: @sydan Due to lack of reputation it wont let me show images.  Something that will help you more is the format of a file path.  This is how my file paths are :   <Folder Path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ohsa.org.mt" Name="ohsa.org.mt" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not inner text, What you need is to specify the Attribute because you are using like Path="C:\..."

So Do like this

```
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(ofd.FileName);

        foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.SelectNodes("JobInfo/Folders/Folder"))
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[]{node.Attributes["Path"].InnerText});

    }
```